# S3 API object storage get auth token issue

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get auth token for S3 API storage account

Storage type id is 24 (S3 API)

I am providing a valid username value for 'X-Auth-User'.

```
headers = {
    'X-Auth-User': 'xyz:xyz',
    'X-Auth-Key': API_KEY,
}

auth_token_resp = requests.get('https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0', headers=headers)
```

> Unauthorized
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested.

How can I get auth token and order the S3 API object storage.

This same API is working for Swift.

Answer (score 0):

please review documentation S3 is not the same swift:

https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-endpoints.html

here the documentation about authentication using the API

https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-authentication.html

Regards